# Python Lists and Files

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop

I need help figuring out how to output every word in a list that has whatever letter the user picks in it.
For example if my list was ["Bob", "Mary", "Jezebel"] and I ask the user to pick any letter and they pick the letter z, I want to find out how I can output Jezebel only from the list using a for loop.

```
import os.path
def name_file():
    # asking user name of file
    file_name = input("What is the name of the file to read the names from?")
    while not os.path.exists(file_name):
        print("This file does not exist")
        file_name = input("What is the name of the file to read the names from?")
    return file_name
name_file()

file_opener = open("5letterwords.txt","r")
read_line_by_line = file_opener.readlines()

word_list = []

for line in read_line_by_line:
    word_list.append(line.strip())
print(word_list)

letter = input("Pick a letter of your choosing and every word with that letter will be outputted")
for letter in word_list:
    print (letter in word_list)
```

Above is my current code and the last 3 lines are the part im struggling with. I want to output whatever words that has the letter picked by the user

Answer (score 0):

As the word list contains..  ["Bob", "Mary", "Jezebel"]

**Code:-**

```
word_list=["Bob", "Mary", "Jezebel"]
letter = input("Pick a letter of your choosing and every word with that letter will be outputted")
for word in word_list:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
```

**Output:-**

```
Pick a letter of your choosing and every word with that letter will be outputted
z
Jezebel
```

**Note-: All the word which contains "z" will be printed. if you wanted that only the first word in a word_list should be printed which contains letter "z" than you should apply break statement.**

```
for word in word_list:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
        break   #Like this
```